# R barplot x axes length and labeling

Tags: r

I want to use a barplot to show measured displacement against a gradient (y axis) over a time unit (x axis). The plotting works, however, I need to be able to define the length of the x axis (starting at 1 : 366 == which is the min and max of all my measurements in the full df) - so that it all barplots I produce have the same length (start and end point). Also, I want to have a label every 10 units of time along the x axis. I have not managed to create such. A reproducible example and the steps I have below:

```
daybeg<-as.numeric(c("291.37561", "75.62574" , "196.37539" ,  "69.62543" ,  "93.37560" , 
"107.62561" , "196.62595" , "211.62557" , "174.87560" , "326.87566",
"224.12542"  , "72.12561" , "246.62544" ,  "61.62574" , "358.37556" , 
"299.12561" , "109.12560"  , "83.87560" , "16.87560"  , "47.87542"))

xdisspeed<-as.numeric(c("135.7357914","24.8621089",
"-216.3525499","159.3480878","124.7417427","-44.1748472",
"-271.1816785","-14.1738848","-61.0028242","-4.1711081", "-149.8402704","22.5010417",
" 0.9998611","21.6817234","-38.4359401", "-1116.1317216","145.0873211","222.6752537",
" 5.2331234","0.9992136"))

df<-data.frame(daybeg,xdisspeed)

ord<-df[order(df$daybeg),]
bpdisplan <- barplot(ord$xdisspeed,axes=T,ylim=c(-1200,1200),  
   names.arg=round(ord$daybeg,0), 
   xlab="Days since 10 January.", axis.lty=1,tcl = 0.25, 
   ylab="Displacement (km)")
```

Comment: Barplots generally have discrete values along one of the axis but here you seem to have two continuous vales and it doesn't seem like you want to do any binning. There seems to be a lot of variability in the number of days between observations `diff(ord$daybeg)`. I don't clearly understand what you want the end product to look like. Do you want a bunch if irregularly spaced (possibly overlapping bars)? Do you want some sort of needle plot (ie `plot(xdisspeed~daybeg, ord, type="h")`? Or even just a line plot (ie `plot(xdisspeed~daybeg, ord, type="l"); abline(h=0, lty=2)`)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The sample data frame is only a fraction of the measurements. Actually the data frame has 700-1000 rows (measurements taken between dates 1-366). Irregular spaced and overlapping bars is what I need, and an x axis label from 1 -366, by=10. plot(xdisspeed~daybeg, ord, type="h",lwd=5) is close to what it should look like.

Comment: Just corrected the seq in the example to 1:366 (from 0:366)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you are describing doesn't match any sort of standard description of a barplot. If you just want to draw a bunch of awkwardly postitioned boxes, then

```
plot(xdisspeed~daybeg, ord, type="n", xaxt="n")
w<-3
with(ord, rect(daybeg-w/2, 0, daybeg+w/2,xdisspeed, col="#eeeeee"))
axis(1, at=seq(0, 355, by=10), cex.axis=.60)
```

[image]

Note that R won't draw axis labels that overlap by default so i reduced the font size to get it to print every 10, but that will depend on your particular graphics device and output size as to what values will actually work.

Comment: This is the solution to what I was looking for. Also, you have a point regarding the use if barplot for my data presentation. The needle plot might be more appropriate.